# How to find an especific element on a queue?

Tags: c++, position, find, queue

I'm really newbie in c++, and now I'm trying to find a specific number in a queue, but it doesn't work, I'm getting this error:

- Line 34 cannot convert 'node' to 'node*' in initialization.
- Line 71 could not convert 'q' from 'node*' to 'node'.

what I'm doing is this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct node {
        int data;
        node * next;
        }queue;
        queue *Q, *first, *final=NULL;


void push()
{
     int number;    
     cout<<"Enter the number: ";
     cin>>number;
     Q=new node; 
     Q->data=number;
     Q->next=NULL;
     if(first==NULL)
     {
        final=first=Q;
     }
     else
     {
         final->next = Q;
         final = Q;    

     }
}

void findElement(node q ,int number)
{

     node * Q=q;
     int i=0,flag=0;

     while(Q!=NULL)
     {
        if(Q->data==number)
        {
           cout<<"Found in position: "<<i<<endl;
           flag=1;
        }
        Q=Q->next;
        i++;
     }
     if(flag==0)
     {
        cout<<"\n\nNot found..."<<endl;
     }
}

int main()
{
    int number,x;
    node *q=NULL;

    cout<<"1 Push"<<endl;
    cout<<"2 Find"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    do
    {  
        switch (x)
        {
        case 1:
            push();
            break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"\n\nEnter the number you want to find: ";
            cin>>number;
            findElement(q,number);
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Invalid option..."<<endl;
            break;

        }
    }while (x!=0); 
}
```

I know that my program might be really bad, but I'm trying really hard to learn, so please if you can tell me what I'm doing wrong it'd mean so much to me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: change header to void findElement(node* q ,int number);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have other issues involved, but for those specific errors, you are trying to copy a node to a node*.  The latter is a pointer.

```
//This won't work.
node * Q=q;

// This will.  (However...)
node* Q = &q;
```

Similarly, on line 71

```
findElement( q, number);
```

q is of type node* (pointer to node), but findElement takes type node.   Perhaps you should change 
    findElement( node q, int number )
to
    findElement( node* q, int number )

Pointers can take a while to wrap your head around, and the syntax is subtle.  They are a key point to the language though.
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers.htm

Comment: Thanks I got that part of the pointers, well I guess..
I did what you suggested, but the program is not working, I mean I still without find the positions of the numbers, do you know why?

Comment: There is something wonky w/ my system where I can't compile the code I copy & paste from the browser. I would suggest that you put an } else { clause in findElement() to print out the contents. That will at least give you a hint as to what's going on.

Comment: Ok, I got it,I did it and is working now, thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem!  Hang in there.